# Restored database taking massive amount of space

Tags: sql-server, ssms, shrink, transaction-log

I restored a database with a 1.5gb .bak file. Everything works fine except the restored database now takes 64gb of space.

I've heard about shrinking databases and log files but how should I find out what is it that takes so much space and what I can "shrink" so that the data itself won't change. I need this production backup data in my development environment as it is.

I don't need full logs in the development environment where I'm doing the restoring. How to find out is it the data or the logs that take more space?

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2017

Comment: backup files are usually compressed so this is expected behaviour, try shrinking the files, it won't delete data, it will free up space that has been allocated but not used. you need to specify some more details too, as you've not said if it's the log or data file that are taking up the bulk of the space and whether you need the full logs in the restoring environment.

Comment: I'll add these details to the question

Comment: Check if this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48617895/sql-server-c-drive-memory-issue/48620616#48620616 It deals with similar issue; shrinking log file will not harm the data in any way.

Comment: Sounds like you haven't taken any transaction log backups, if you don't backup and truncate the log it will just grow and grow - especially if you are doing large operations like deleting all records from a table and re-filling it etc.

Comment: Can you delete tables from the restored database? Try figuring out which tables consume the most space and either delete rows from them, or delete the whole table... If you do end up deleting rows, perform a shrink operation after to reduce the space used...

Comment: @bastos.sergio -- you are advising him to delete underlying data in order to gain disk space before shrinking the db?  That does not seem like very good advice.  Why would you assume that he can just delete data?  Also, deleting data won't help if he is running in the full recovery model and the problem is a large log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe logs?

I suggest you to analyze if that fits you. Make the backups much shorter: [See More](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/copy-only-backups-sql-server)

```
BACKUP DATABASE XXXXX TO DISK 'C:\XXX.bak' WITH COPY_ONLY
```

---

You can also change the [Recovery Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/recovery-models-sql-server) from Full (Default) to Simple, after the restore.

[image: That shows where you can change it]

---

Then [SHRINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/shrink-a-database) it

---

I'm honestly not sure if all of those are necessary, but that works for me to reduce space. Maybe shrinking before changing recovery model is better, or maybe one of those are not the best pratices.

Answer (score 1):

You could see what is the file size of a database in your backup using

```
restore filelistonly from disk = 'here_the_full_pass_to_your_backup_including_file_name'
```

So you could plan how much space it will need.

> How to find out is it the data or the logs that take more space?

Please update your question with the results of

```
use MyDB;
exec sp_spaceused;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question: "How to find out if it is the data or the logs that take more space?"

Answer:  Here is one way.  Right click your database in Sql Mgt. Studio, click Reports=>Standard Reports and then disk usage.

If you don't understand the differences between the full and simple recovery models, I encourage you to do some reading.  Also understand the consequences of shrinking files and auto-grow.  Shrinking files won't cause you to lose committed data, but will cause a performance hit later on if and when Sql needs to auto-grow files.

If you don't need the full recovery model and aren't concerned about auto-grow, then change it to simple or bulk-logged and then shrink the log file(s).

If you are not concerned about auto-grow, then you can also shrink data file(s).